# wxPython, using a field from an imported class

Tags: python, wxpython

First important to state that I am an amateur programmer.

Building a personal software in python/wxPython connected to a MySQL DB

My problem:

trying to write one form that will access classes from an imported file.
The form accesses at any one time 4 related tables on the database.

Three(3) of these tables are always the same.  The fourth can be one of two tables.

The tables that are always accessed : session, cardio and notes
The tables that can vary are: physical or machine

I have placed the data fields in wx.Panel classes for each of the tables mentioned above.  The mainForm's menu calls the input form with a reference to either the physical or the machine parameter.  The appropriate form is displayed with its data fields.

My problem is I can't access these imported fields to load data from the database.

Sections of my code:

Mainform: dailyResultsV2.py

```
import inputForm as IF

# Menu Event:
```

def OnShowBikeRecs(self, event):

```
self.bikeedit = IF.inputForm(None, -1, "Bike Record Management", size=(925,650), name="bike")
    self.bikeedit.Show()
    self.bikeedit.Center()
```

Called Form: inputForm.py

```
class inputForm(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

    self.EXERCISE = kwargs['name']


    # create a panel
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
    self.panel.BackgroundColour = (200, 230, 250)
    self.filterSetup()
    self.sessionSection = IFC.tblSession(self.panel,-1)
    self.sessionSection.BackgroundColour = (200, 230, 250)
    if self.EXERCISE == 'walk':
        self.physicalSection = IFC.tblPhysical(self.panel,-1)
    else:
        self.machineSection = IFC.tblMachine(self.panel,-1)

    self.cardioSection = IFC.tblcardio(self.panel,-1)
    self.notesSection = IFC.tblNotes(self.panel,-1)
    self.buttonSetup()
    self.topsizer()
```

The preceding class creates an input form which will include all the fields from the physical table or the machine table.

My problem how to I access these fields to add data from the database or update the database.  (One side note this is a physical training database).

example of the imported classes: inputFormClasses.py

```
class tblMachine(wx.Panel):    
def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

    self.BackgroundColour = (200, 230, 250)

    # The columns
    # machine_ID - not displayed        machine_session_FK  - not displayed     machine_level  - not displayed
    # machine_Type_FK   machine_Distance    machine_AvgSpeed   machine_MaxSpeed     machine_Duration     machine_ODO     machine_RunFK - ComboBox           

    self.runNames = []      # ComboBox List

    self.machineLabel_st = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Machine", style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    self.machineType_st = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Type", style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    self.machineType_tc = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, value="Biking",  style=wx.TE_CENTRE)
    self.machineDistance_st = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Distance", style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    self.machineDistance_tc = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.TE_CENTRE)
    self.machineAvgSpeed_st = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Avg. Speed", style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    self.machineAvgSpeed_tc = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.TE_CENTRE)
    self.machineMaxSpeed_st = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Max Speed", style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    self.machineMaxSpeed_tc = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.TE_CENTRE)
    self.machineDuration_st = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Duration", style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    self.machineDuration_mtc = masked.TimeCtrl(self, -1, fmt24hr=True)
    self.machineODO_st = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Odometer", style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    self.machineODO_tc = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.TE_CENTRE)
    self.machineRun_st = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Run", style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    self.machineRun_cbo = wx.ComboBox(self, -1, choices = self.getRunNames(self.runNames), style=wx.CB_READONLY)  # get the list of runs for comboBox

    # create machine sizer
    self.MachineSizer    = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=5, vgap=5)
```

How to I access for example: self.machineType_tc on my form ?

Comment: Thanks Lance for the Input.  I'm sorry I was not clear. I have not problem accessing my Database.  My problem was accessing the programmed data form.  I believe I solved my own problem.  To access a specific variable in the class I must prefix the control variable name by the variable that instantiated the class. (I hope I'm saying this right)

Answer (score 0):

Check out sqlite3 library: I used it to do something similar:

```
import sqlite3
def insert_user(cursor,username,password,port,steps,lat,long):   
    try:    
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mydb VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)",            (username,password,port,steps,lat,long))
        return "Success"
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        return "Failure"
```

I hope this helps.